# While loops in a program running

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this program that I am writing and I want it to quit.

Meaning, when I type in `Q`, or give it an input of `Q`, it should show me..

```
Press Q to quit: Q   
And it should show >>> in next line
```

But so far I have:

```
list = ['Approval', 'Range', 'Plurality', 'IRV', 'Borda', 'Q']
input_prompt = prompt_from_list('Select a voting system or Q to quit:', list)
while input_prompt != 'Q':

approval_file = open(APPROVAL_BALLOT_FILENAME, 'r')
approval = approval_file.readlines()
approval_file.close()




if input_prompt == 'Approval':
    print('Running for Approval')
    prompt_riding = prompt_for_riding("Which riding would you like to see results for? (Enter a number between 0 and 307, or all.):",
                      307)

    list = format_approval_list(approval, prompt_riding)
    a = vs.voting_approval(list)

    country = print_country_results(a[1])
elif input_prompt == 'Range':
    print('Running for Range')
    prompt_riding = prompt_for_riding("Which riding would you like to see results for? (Enter a number between 0 and 307, or all.):",
                      307)
         print prompt_riding
```

Now it should continue the loop.. for after the we input prompt and it should go to prompt_riding, but it doesnt...:(

```
>>>Select a voting system or Q to quit:
 Approval, Range, Plurality, IRV, Borda, Q
Approval
Running for Approval
Which riding would you like to see results for? (Enter a number between 0 and 307, or all.):0
Which riding would you like to see results for? (Enter a number between 0 and 307, or all.):

It should show me.. 
Select a voting system or Q to quit:
  Approval, Range, Plurality, IRV, Borda, Q
```

Is there a possible way I can close the infinite while loop?

Comment: Why are you having colon after every line?

Comment: So that it would show in the next line.. i am new to stack overflow so not so familiar with the formatting sorry

Comment: @user1853961.. For formatting your code. Paste it here. Select complete code, and `Ctrl + K` to add code tags.

Comment: Do you want that the program loops without you approving each loop?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
input_prompt = '' # To get into the loop first time

# Start loop
while input_prompt != 'Q':

    # Now ask for voting system
    input_prompt = prompt_from_list('Select a voting system or Q to quit:', list)
        ...

    if input_prompt == 'Approval':
        ...
        prompt_riding = input("Which riding would you like to see results for? (Enter a number between 0 and 307, or all.):")

        # If the user has selected to Quit
        if prompt_riding == 'Q':
            break # Exit loop

        # Continue checking what prompt_input is
        ...
```

Comment: what would be my raw_input?? and am i not using an infinite loop

Comment: @user1853961 `raw_input()` returns whatever you input - read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) or try it in your interpreter and see what it does :)

Comment: This method works except its stopping loop at certain point.. i dunno how to specify

Comment: @user1853961 I've updated my answer to match your new information :)

Comment: Thanks soo much. Got it!...Use null value for input prompt

Answer (score 0):

I I were you I would use tkinter to manipulate events:

```
# respond to a key without the need to press enter
import Tkinter as tk
def keypress(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Q':
        root.destroy()
    x = event.char

root = tk.Tk()
print "Press Q to Quit:"
print ">>> "
root.bind_all('<Key>', keypress)
# don't show the tk window
root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```